# Invalid input shapes for a CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

This is my first ML project done without any tutorials so apologies if this is a silly question.

Anyways, I'm making a CNN classifier that simply puts images in 1 of 2 categories (slouched or straight back)

I can't seem to get the input images used for prediction to match the dimensions that the model accepts. It is supposed to input 100x100 grayscale images. It keeps on returning this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 100, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='reshape_input'), name='reshape_input', description="created by layer 'reshape_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 100).
```

- 

**I have tried various methods of resizing and reshaping and gray scaling (even though it is not in the code snippet), but I can't find something that works***

Here are the relevant bits of code:

```
print(slouchClassifier.predict(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(frame, (100,100)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)))
```

```
    def predict(self, image):
        return self.model.predict(image)
```

```
 def trainModel(self, training, epochs = 1):
        x = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
            training,
            labels='inferred',
            label_mode='categorical',
            class_names=None,
            color_mode='grayscale',
            batch_size=32,
            image_size=(100, 100),
        )

        self.model.fit(x, batch_size= self.batchSize, verbose = 2, epochs = epochs) #Verbose = status updates on training
```

```
def createModel(self):
        #Model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Reshape((100,100,1)))

        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Dropout(0.1))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(1024))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dense(512))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dense(64))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dense(2))
        model.add(Activation('softmax'))

        # initiate RMSprop optimizer
        opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0001)

        # Let's train the model using RMSprop
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    optimizer=opt,
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
        
        return model
```

I hope this is enough information for you! Let me know if you need more information about the code.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

> tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 100, 1)

Your model expects an input shape of `(100, 100, 1)`. However, you used this to prepare the input:

```
slouchClassifier.predict(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(frame, (100,100)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
```

`cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` gets rid of the channel dimension entirely, resulting in an image of shape `(100, 100)`. You need to add the channel dimension back. One way is `np.expand_dims(img, -1)`.

For example,

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(frame, (100, 100)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
img = np.expand_dims(img, -1)
pred = slouchClassifier.predict(img)
```